# Get Date or Time for, Server

Tags: java, date, netbeans, time

I have this codes to get the current date on my desktop.

```
SimpleDateFormat dnow = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
text.setText(dnow.format(new java.util.Date()));
```

Now I have a server and computers,
how can I get the time for the server,
if I install the program, the computers will have the
time of the server in my program, cause my database is located in the server.

Comment: You can use NTP to synchronize hosts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol.  You SQL-based applications should *always* use the server time (e.g. "gettime()") and *never* pass the time/date from a client.

Comment: Question is unclear. What means "if I install the program, the computers will have the time of the server" ?

Comment: the other computers will have the time of the server in the program

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the server date and time if the server does not provide any service to do the same. So you can either have a service installed on the server and call it from your system.

If the server is a database server then there is an alternative to connect to the database server and run query to get the time such as these:

- Oracle

  ```
  SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
  ```

  or

  ```
  SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
  ```
- MySQL

  ```
  SELECT CURDATE();
  ```
- SQL Server

  ```
  SELECT GETDATE()
  GO
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want get the server's current date, you can request the value "System.currentTimeMillis()" via Servlet or WebService on the server.

```
System.currentTimeMillis() returns number of milliseconds since 1970.
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: its only system not the time of the server

Comment: I mean run System.currentTimeMillis() on your server, then you got your server's time